# Get the list of User stories under the current Iteration

Tags: java, rally

Am trying to get the list of User Stories under the particular Iteration by using

```
storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Iteration.Name", "=", "my Iteration 1"));
```

But if i want the user stories under the current Iteration, is there any other means of Querying? 
 I mean is there any attribute which specifies the current Iteration?

Answer (score 2):

Today should fall in a range between Iteration.StartDate and Iteration.EndDate. Here is WS API query:

```
((Iteration.StartDate <= today) AND (Iteration.EndDate >= today))
```

Endpoint example:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/123&query=((Iteration.StartDate <= today) AND (Iteration.EndDate >= today))&start=1&pagesize=200
```